# Sonarqube Static Code Analysis for Clojure Codes

Tags: java, clojure, sonarqube, leiningen, sonarscanner

I am Using Sonarqube Version **7.5.0.20543**,Sonar Scanner version **sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873** and Sonar-Clojure Plugin (https://github.com/fsantiag/sonar-clojure)

I am trying to Analyse Clojure Codes using Sonarqube. I have added the above Clojure Plugin to the sonar server. I am trying to run sonar-scanner from local path where the code is stored.
Following is the command I am using:-

`sonar-scanner.bat -D"sonar.projectKey=ProjectKey" -D"sonar.sources=." -D"sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000" -D"sonar.login=xxxxxxx"`

This is the error i am getting when i run the command:–

```
at org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandExecutor.execute(CommandExecutor.java:102)
at org.sonar.plugins.clojure.sensors.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:36)
at org.sonar.plugins.clojure.sensors.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:50)
at org.sonar.plugins.clojure.sensors.eastwood.EastwoodSensor.execute(EastwoodSensor.java:47)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:45)
at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(SensorsExecutor.java:65)
at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.withGlobalStrategy(SensorsExecutor.java:80)
at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:65)
at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:74)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:164)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:319)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:314)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:131)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program “lein”: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandExecutor.execute(CommandExecutor.java:74)
… 36 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
… 39 more
```

Is there any other plugin i could use? or is there something that i am not doing correctly?

**Ps. I am fairly new to both Sonarqube and Clojure**

Comment: I used this tutorial before: https://dev.solita.fi/2019/03/11/code-quality-inspection-for-clojure-with-sonarqube.html
It's brief and worked for me well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you cut off the beginning of the Exception stacktrace (it should say something about "Exception" at the beginning).

However, there is a big clue towards the bottom:

```
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program “lein”: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandExecutor.execute(CommandExecutor.java:74)
… 36 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
```

Your SonarSource code is trying to find a system program named `lein`.  It is apparently not on the system PATH.  I'm guessing you are using `lein` wrong in trying to invoke the SonarQube scanner.

I found some info that may help you debug your installation:

- https://www.jishuwen.com/d/2MVR
- https://clojars.org/sonar-clojure-native-plugin
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/azrpym/code_quality_inspection_for_clojure_using/
- https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Other+Plugins
- https://github.com/fsantiag/sonar-clojure
- https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/